# The leading minor of order 4 is not positive definite in npplreg

Tags: r, regression

I am running the following code:

```
mydata1 = data.frame(dataset)
mydata1 <- na.omit(mydata1)
bw <- npplregbw(mydata1$X1 ~ mydata1$X2 + mydata1$X3 + mydata1$X4 + mydata1$effect_1993 + mydata1$effect_1994 + mydata1$effect_1995 + mydata1$effect_1996 + mydata1$effect_1997 + mydata1$country_2 + mydata1$country_3 + mydata1$country_4 + mydata1$country_5 + mydata1$country_6 + mydata1$effect_1998 + mydata1$effect_1999 + mydata1$effect_2000 + mydata1$effect_2001 + mydata1$effect_2002 + mydata1$effect_2003 + mydata1$effect_2004 + mydata1$effect_2005 + mydata1$effect_2006 + mydata1$effect_2007 + mydata1$effect_2008 + mydata1$effect_2009 + mydata1$effect_2010 + mydata1$effect_2011 + mydata1$effect_2012 + mydata1$effect_2013 + mydata1$effect_2014 + mydata1$effect_2015 + mydata1$effect_2016 + mydata1$effect_2017 + mydata1$effect_2018 + mydata1$effect_2019 + mydata1$effect_2020 + mydata1$effect_2021|mydata1$X5 + mydata1$X6 + mydata1$X7 + mydata1$X8, data = mydata1, na.action = na.omit)
summary(bw)
reg_np <- npplreg(bw)
```

The code is running fine except the last command which gives the following error:

```
Error in chol.default(t(model.matrix(model)) %*% model.matrix(model)) : 
the leading minor of order 4 is not positive definite
```

My data do not have 0 (except the fixed effects data) or NA values.

Is there any way I can proceed with the npplreg regression without getting that error?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Does the answer here help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064686/error-in-chol-defaultcxx-the-leading-minor-of-order-is-not-positive-definite

Comment: Unfortunately no. I've checked that answer already but the case is different there. Thanks anyways!